# What's the purpose of "toggle_flag" in GDB PEDA command?

Tags: gdb

I'm watching a video which explain how to solve a challenge on root-me.org

https://asciinema.org/a/22558

the command he used is

> toggle_flag 'S'

I google it to know what was the purpose of the command toggle_flag but didn't find anything. So I downloaded GDB PEDA to check if the was some useful informations using the command

> help all

which is suppose to list all command available in GDB PEDA...But didn't find any useful..

So doe anyone  can explain me what "toggle_flag 'S' " does mean ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is instruction after break on which `toggle_flag 'S'` is executed:

```
   0x8048410 <main+32>: call   0x8058a70 <ptrace>
   0x8048415 <main+37>: add    esp,0x10
   0x8048418 <main+40>: test   eax,eax
=> 0x804841a <main+42>: jns    0x8048436 <main+70>
```

You can see here the check for the presence of a debugger with help of `ptrace` function. In C it will be look like that:

```
if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 1, 0) == -1) {
    // Under debugger
}
```

After `ptrace` call at `0x8048410` its return value is stored in `eax` and
command `test eax, eax` sets Sign Flag (SF) if eax is negative (i.e. if debugger is present). We don't want the program detected that it is under debugger so with command `toggle_flag 'S'` we toggle SF, i.e. set it to 0.